# Specific Classes not being garbage collected (Unusual static class hierarchy)

Tags: java, serialization, static, garbage-collection, inner-classes

I have an unusual Class structure, when I'm thinking may be leading to some GC issues.

I have a Class: `public class Styles`

This contains a: `public static class Style implements Serializable`

Then I have a: `public abstract class StyleDescription extends Style`

Which contains a: `public static final class CellStyleDescription extends StyleDescription`

So, the class hierarchy of CellStyleDescription is pretty unusual.

Instances of this Class are created, serialized, then later read back in and processed.
I know static classes do not handled differently by the garbage collector, but always at the end of processing, I have millions of these Classes still still in memory.
Nothing in my code looks like it could be contributing to the instances not being GC'd, except this Class hierarchy.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?
Or know of anything to look out for with regard to GC and serialization of static classes?

Cheers,
Ro

**EDIT**:

What I should have pointed out is these classes are created then added to another Object (CellInfo) as member variables .... I can see the instances of this class (which is the only container of CellStyleDescription) being GC'd

Comment: Show some code. Without it you will not get meaningful answers.

Comment: I'll prepare a code sample to reproduce.

Comment: Depending on the size it may not be practical to review the code. There is nothing here to suggest GC might get confused. It is most likely either normal behavior or a memory leak in your code. Try using a profiler, or maybe even before that try GC using jconsole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the problem.

Like I said, the Objects were being Serialized, then later read back in.
It turns out that OubjectOutputStream keeps a reference to every single Object that gets written out.
Objects are compared using the **System.identityHashCode(obj)** method, and not the Object Hashcode.

More details are here: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/SER10-J.+Avoid+memory+and+resource+leaks+during+serialization

Either way, the solution was to reset the ObjectOutputStream regularly

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `static` applied to a class just means it is the same as any other top-level class, and not a nested class, even though its declaration appears inside another class.

Garbage collection is governed by the lifetime of *references* to classes. If you create lots of instances and keep references to those instances, then they will not be garbage collected. There is nothing wrong with your class hierarchy.  Without any more information it is impossible to provide a more meaningful answer.

Comment: Thanks, what I should have pointed out is these classes are created then added to another Object as member variables .... I can see the instances of this class (which is the only container of CellStyleDescription) being GC'd

Answer (score 1):

In first place, your hierarchy is not that uncommon.  In second place, objects are generally not collected until memory is really needed.  You should try filling-up memory with other objects and see if they still are there.  If they **are** then most probably you are not releasing all objects as you think.

You **could** have an inadvertent object retention problem with the `abstract` class.  Can you make it `static` too?